# MVC 4 razor view, how to let view translate @model or @form that is being loaded from database?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im creating CMS that stores all contents in the database as text (nvarchar).

Right now im using AJAX to load the page and grab the page content from database. My problem is that, i cannot translate @model or @using or any @'s that are loaded from database via AJAX.

I want the page behave like the normal page view reader that translate like @form into  ... or any @'s like that.

Is it possible? Or maybe any alternatives which i can manipulate the view.cshtml?

Thanks,
Alvin

Comment: You are storing Razor code in your database?

Comment: Look out further for [Razor Parsing engine.](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hi Siva, this is exactly what im looking for... Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter is here [Razor Engine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/). Thanks Siva Gopal for the answer.

Comment: I recommend RazorEngine, but use the precompiled [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/) or the [new project home](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), not this old Codeplax link.